# How to upload picture when register in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I'm trying to upload an image in laravel default user registration. I'm using laravel ui package.

Here is create method in RegisterController

```
  public function create(array $data) {
        if (request()->hasFile('image')) {
          $image = request()->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
            request()->file('image')->storeAs('avatars', $image, 'public');
    }
    return User::create([
        'name'     => $data['name'],
        'email'    => $data['email'],
        'address'  => $data['address'],
        'image'    => $image ,
        'contact'  => $data['contact'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);
```

I'm getting this error

Undefined variable: image"

Comment: have you `dd($data)` and see if you are getting the image?

Comment: Yes, I've seen it. I'm getting the image

Comment: is the image being stored in the storage folder?

Comment: No, It is not stored into storage folder

Comment: in the user model in `fillable` add `image` column name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the User model:

```
protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'image',             //add this
        'contact',           //add this
    ];
```

Comment: I did this. But I forgot to add enctype="multipart/form-data" in form. My problem has solved. Thank you so much

Comment: Great. glad to be of any help.